# How to Remove a Branch from the Middle of the Hierarchy?

Tags: tfs, branch

I have a Team Project created with the "Standard" branch pattern from the ALM Rangers' Branching guidance:

[image: Standard Branch Hierarchy]

After creating it, I found that I only really needed the "Basic" pattern. That is, I don't need the "Service Pack" branch.

Is there a way for me to remove the "Service Pack" branch and "heal" the hierarchy so that "Release" is under "Main" in the hierarchy? Right now, every changeset in the "Service Pack" hierarchy has a corresponding changeset in the "Release" hierarchy, as "Service Pack" has just been in the way.

Comment: Why in the world would anyone downvote this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to not remove or reparent.

The service pack branch is the "service pack branch" in name only.  Delete the "release" branch and rename the "service pack branch" to "release".

Comment: Simple and elegant, and the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Branches in TFS are unfortunately old-fashioned (or, "Dinosaur-like" if you ask Torvalds ;) in that once created, the structure is set and cannot be changed. I believe you will have to create a new **Release** Branch directly below the **Main**, and then perform a [baseless merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668976.aspx) from the old Release branch to the new. I think you should use the `/noprompt` parameter to the merge command to stop the "Resolve Conflicts" dialog to show.

This will give you more conflicts than really needed, since TFS won't know what ancestor to use. But since you will want to take all from the original Release branch, you can use the command `tf resolve /recursive /auto:TakeTheirs` to tell TFS to always take the changes in the source branch.

After that, you should be able to remove the old branch tree.

Complicated, but not impossible.

Comment: when using the /discard parameter with the baseless merge you don't get conflicts and no code is changed on either side

Comment: By the time of this comment, TFS already had a "reparent" feature, allowing this very kind of change in structure.

Answer (score 4):

Well I don't know about old version of `TFS`, but at least in `TFS2012`/`VS2013`, you can do:

1. A Baseless merge from **Main** -> **Release**
2. `Source Control Explorer` > `Branching and Merging` > `Reparent`, choose **Main** (the new parent)

Done!

Comment: Sometimes the wizard window takes time to load the possible parents

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me in a similar scenario

```
tf merge /baseless /recursive /noprompt /discard $/TFS/Path/To/Release $/TFS/Path/To/Main
```

then:

- delete "Service Pack" branch
- check-in "Main" and "Service Pack"

now you can do normal GUI merges from "Release" to "Main"

**NOTE: As many people already have mentioned, be careful with baseless merges they can bite you in the jewels later on down the line when abused.**