# Excluded branches showing on TFS branch diagram

Tags: .net, tfs, visual-studio-2013

I am using TFS2010, through VS2013, and when I go to my master branch, `Branching and Merging` > `View Hierarchy`. It shows up some deleted branches. They were excluded by myself long ago, but I can't remove them from diagram.

Here are the hierarchy view:

[image]

I already tried to remove all the checkouts from all the collaborators through TFS Sidekicks, but without any luck. I tried to Google it, and also tried other questions here, [including this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23685333/821054), which I have replied but does not apply to the same problem...

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/507353/tfs-2010-branch-hierarchy-view-showing-branches-that-were-deleted

Comment: Thanks @Isaiah4110, but I could not find if I have to install any patch or update

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19041034/tfs-branch-refused-to-go

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am yet to find a proper solution to this problem, but I could find an work-around... That is, *convert the deleted branch to a folder!* It simply won't show on the hierarchy after that.

**In VS `Source Control Explorer`:**

1. Click the `Show Delete Branches` icon
2. Find and `Right-Click` the deleted branch in the Tree
3. Select `Branching and Merging` > `Convert to Folder`
4. **Done**, the branch is no longer in the hierarchy

[Found it in the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2341186/821054)